# C# object to array

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, collections, casting

Using reflection I have an object which I need to cast into an iterable list of items (type unknown, will be object). Using the Watch window I can see my object is an array of some type as it tells me the number of elements and I can explode the tree view to see the elements themselves.

Firstly, I need to check that the object passed is some kind of array (might be List, might be object[], etc). Then I need to iterate through that array. However, I can't do the type conversion.

Here's how I'm using it (abbreviated):

```
    private static void Example(object instance, PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        object anArray = propInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
        ArrayList myList = anArray as ArrayList;
        foreach (object element in myList)
        {
            // etc
        }
    }
```

I've tried various different casts. The above doesn't raise an exception but mylist is null when anArray actually exists and contains items. The actual instance being saved is a strongly-typed List<> but could take a limited subset of forms if necessary. But the point of the exercise is that this Example() method doesn't know the basic type of the property.

Comment: you can find out the type of object from instance.GetType() and you can compare it with desirebale type using `is`, e.g. `if (instance.GetType() is IEnumerable)`

Comment: @Bad Display Name that's now how the *is* keyword works, what you're doing there is attempting to cast from System.Type to System.Collection.IEnumerable, which doesn't work since System.Type doesn't implement that interface. perhaps you meant **typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType())**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Casting it to an ArrayList is only going to work if the object actually *is* an ArrayList. It wont work with a System.Array, or a System.Collections.Generic.List`1 for example.

I think what you actually should do is cast it to IEnumerable, since that is your only requirement to loop over it...

```
object anArray = propInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
IEnumerable enumerable = anArray as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach(object element in enumerable)
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: matt... is that you?! It's Marlon.... anyway, this doesn't work, IEnumerable needs a type parameter (maybe this was possible on an old version of .NET)

Comment: @Cloud: Not correct. There is [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-8.0) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 18):

Try to cast to `IEnumerable`. This is the most basic interface all enumerables, arrays, lists etc. implement.

```
IEnumerable myList = anArray as IEnumerable;
if (myList != null)
{
    foreach (object element in myList)
    {
        // ... do something
    }
}
else
{
    // it's not an array, list, ...
}
```

Comment: No - it needs a type parameter, this doesn't work

Comment: @Cloud: Not correct. There is [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-8.0) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-8.0)

Comment: If you do get the "Using generic type 'IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments" error, then you need to use the System.Collections namespace, that is where the IEnumerable definition is. IEnumerable<T> lives in System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 14):

Simply Try This

```
 string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)yourOjbect).Cast<object>()
                             .Select(x => x.ToString())
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the simplest way if it is primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var myList = anArray as IEnumerable;
    if (mylist != null)
    { 
        foreach (var element in myList)
        {
            // etc
        }
    }
```

You might also need to specify the generic type of the IEnumerable, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast it to `IEnumerable` if it is a collection of any sorts (array, list, etc.). Also `PropertyInfo` contains a `PropertyType` property which you could use to find out the actual type if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Just in My case I need to define data type `IEnumerable<string>`

```
var myList = anArray as IEnumerable<string>;
```