# How to access Object by index C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object, indexing, foreach

I have a foreach loop in C# which return some inventory data, the property `location_id` returns as an `object[]`. the loop as follows,

```
foreach (XmlRpcStruct item in result)
{
   object obj =  item["location_id"];
}
```

in debugger, I see the object as following,
[image]

so I guess object is something like

```
obj[0] = 12
obj[1] = "WH/Stock"
```

I tried to access the `obj` like `obj[0]`  then I get

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

So, how can I access the object by index to retrieve the values such as `12` and `WH/Stock`

Comment: "but that doesn't work": What error do you get?

Comment: When trying with `obj[0]` did you get an compiler error or an execution error or something?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, then i get the error `cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6438062/5174469)

Comment: I don't know why this was "Closed as off topic" because I'm struggling with the exact same thing. Gotta love SO and their hubris.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cast the `obj` as object[] using:

```
var list = (object[])obj;
```

Then you can use `list[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well for me.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer. :)

Comment: great answer, thank you sir @Emad !

Comment: It is also known as boxing and unboxing an object https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/what-is-object-type-boxing-and-unboxing-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Specify object array type:

```
object[] obj =  item["location_id"];
```

Or, even simplier, let the compiler infer type:

```
var obj =  item["location_id"];
```

Comment: Tried it already, then you'll get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` compile error.