# C# Cast object to IEnumerable<T> and use Linq extensions when the enumerable type is a value type e.g. enum

Tags: c#, linq, collections, casting

How can I cast to an `IEnumerable<T>` so that I can use Linq extensions methods (`Count()`, `Distinct()`) in a method receiving an object value if I know the type is an enumerable type?

A simple cast to `IEnumerable<object>` works for reference types, but it doesn't for value types like enums, for example:

```
StringComparison[] myArray = new StringComparison[] {
  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase,
  StringComparison.Ordinal
};

void DoSomething(object value) {
    IEnumerable<object> items = (IEnumerable<object>) value;

    // use the enumerable with System.Linq.Enumerable extensions
    // items.Count()
    // items.Distinct()
}

DoSomething(myArray);
```

With an enum the cast throws `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.StringComparison[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable^1[System.Object]'.'`

Other answers (e.g. [C# object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438015/c-sharp-object-to-array)) suggest ways of doing this by casting to the non-generic `IEnumerable`. Unfortunately the extension methods I want (`Count()` and `Distinct()`) aren't available for non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Background: The above example is simplified. My actual use case is that I've written a custom `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` that performs a check on an enumerable attribute property. `ValidationAttribute` has a method `IsValid(object value)` that an array of enum values gets passed to and I need to iterate over that property but it fails for this reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `StringComparison[]` implements the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<StringComparison>` interfaces, but does not implement `IEnumerable<object>`.

Unfortunately, you can't use generic covariance to let you assign an object of type `IEnumerable<StringComparison>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<object>`, as `StringComparison` isn't a reference type: you can't just access any old element of the `StringComparison[]` as if it was an object, because it doesn't have the normal object header etc.

What you *can* do is:

```
IEnumerable<object> items = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>();
```

This works because arrays implement `IEnumerable`, and `Enumerable.Cast` is an extension method on `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Every time you fetch an element from `items`, the `Cast<object>()` method gets involved and boxes the `StringComparison` value type into an object.

This means that iterating the list multiple times (as calling lots of linq methods will do) could be expensive, as it will allocate new objects each time. You might want to cache the boxed objects into a list to avoid this cost:

```
List<object> items = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>().ToList();
```